# Wordpress Woocommerce pagination wrong button text for single-language page (Canvas Theme)

Tags: wordpress, pagination, woocommerce, translation

I use the Canvas theme on my german website with a woocommerce shop.
However I have the problem, that my product pagination still uses "previous" and "next" as button texts, even through everything is translated to german.

The Canvas Theme uses an admin-functions.php with following code:

```
$defaults = array(
        'base' => esc_url_raw( add_query_arg( 'paged', '%#%' ) ),
        'format' => '',
        'total' => $max_num_pages,
        'current' => $current,
        'prev_next' => true,
        'prev_text' => __( '&larr; Previous', 'woothemes' ), // Translate in WordPress. This is the default.
        'next_text' => __( 'Next &rarr;', 'woothemes' ), // Translate in WordPress. This is the default.
        'show_all' => false,
        'end_size' => 1,
        'mid_size' => 1,
        'add_fragment' => '',
        'type' => 'plain',
        'before' => '<div class="pagination woo-pagination">', // Begin woo_pagination() arguments.
        'after' => '</div>',
        'echo' => true,
        'use_search_permastruct' => true
    );

    /* Allow themes/plugins to filter the default arguments. */
    $defaults = apply_filters( 'woo_pagination_args_defaults', $defaults );
```

I can neither override this (The comment says not to override anyway) nor find an option in my page's backend to translate this.

Where or how can I change the Text on those buttons?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone ever stumbles across this problem:
I solved it now using the plugin "Say, what!" and translated the String with it. However, this only works, if the String is inside the __() or _e() function.